# Is there a ListCollectionView or a PagedCollectionView classe for Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, listcollectionview, pagedcollectionview

I know there exists a PagedCollectionView class for Silverlight, and a ListCollectionView class for WPF.
But i don't find either of these being available for Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango) latest release.

If i am wrong in my understanding, please let me know which assembly in WP7.5 SDK i should look for either of these types for reference.
If these do not exist for Windows Phone 7.5, is there an alternative (similar capability, of course) class available for use?

Comment: I'm on the same problem, and I'm googling intensively for 6 hours.

Comment: Don't feed the troll ;) I finally sort the collection prior to passing it to the view, so it's already sorted.

Comment: Sure thanks. But i need to do "grouping on the fly", etc. Its a more complex requirement, so i definitely need a specialised class to help handle it. These 2 classes were good candidates, and that is the reason why they exist in the WPF and SL frameworks in the first place. Anyway, i still need to know if there is an alternative class someone has coded for WP7.5? I have not found any so far :(

Comment: That was not required for my project, so I haven't search anymore. Have you seen ICollectionView interface? you may search from there to re-implement a correct behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

There actually is no PagedCollectionView or ListCollectionView available in the Windows Phone SDK. What is available however is the ObservableCollection and one would need to write extension methods to ObservableCollection class to achieve functionality not available by default.